# Display Emoji in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, utf-8, emoji

I've just started out using Tabulator to display a json file as a table. The json file includes some emojis I'd like to display and currently the emojis are just displaying as random text in a Tabulator table's cell.

Tabulator is constructed using javascript in an html file.

I've tried different formatting options but can't get the emojis to display correctly.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What encoding is your page using?

Comment: My page is using standard html encoding

Comment: there is no such thing as _standard html encoding_ . Is your html encoded (for example) as utf-8? then it should display the emojis without any problems. If it is encoded in ASCII then it won't display emojis.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I needed to set the encoding for html. I've just set it to utf-8 and the emojis are now displaying perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Sean - maybe write it up as an answer and show your code for setting the encoding so that it can help someone in the future. tx

Comment: show your JSON and give the examples of the emoji

Comment: @cloned. The document encoding has nothing to do with the character content of HTML. All characters in HTML (and, btw, JavaScript) are Unicode. So, if the document contains emoji, it contains emoji (perhaps by character entity references). If it doesn't, it doesn't (perhaps the emoji were lost if character entity references were not used and the character set doesn't support the emoji characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up a new html file using `<html>` tags, the encoding doesn't necessarily default to UTF-8. To ensure the emojis are displayed correctly in your html file you need to ensure that it is encoded in UTF-8 by setting the charset in a `<meta>` tag.

When you do this the basic structure of your html file will be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        Your head content goes here
    </head>

    <body>
        Your body content goes here
    </body>
</html>
```

Using this structure in your html files will ensure that emoji are displayed correctly.